# Best way to make breakable vertical spaces

Tags: spacing, vspace

I would like to make lecture notes with gaps. But the blanks generated for example by `vspace` are not breakable and start sometimes on a new page.

What is the best way to make breakable vertical spaces ?

Comment: Maybe `\vfill`  or some like `\vspace{12cm minus 11cm}`?

Comment: Probably Ulrike's answer has the right interpretation, but I'm not sure about the question. \vspace *does* break, but it disappears at a break; \vspace* will not break or disappear. Would it be desired to have half the specified gap at the bottom of a page, but no gap at the top of the next page?

Comment: I get the impression you are trying to align a lecture and the notes (beamer?).  I would use paracol to align two sets of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can e.g. create a number of lines with a box in it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn {20}{\hbox{~}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately, it doesn't work inside an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment.

Comment: it works there too, but it should be in a paragraph of its own, so add empty lines (or use something like \par\mbox{~} instead of the \hbox. )